# CSS @media Rule Isn't Working On Mobile Devices

Tags: css, responsive-design

My css @media rules working perfectly on desktop but if i try to view it on mobile, im getting non-responsive view. What could be my problem?

Comment: Consider accepting @YoYo's answer if you found it helpful, in order to award him some reputation points and help future readers of your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add view port inside header tag to let the page resize according to the width of the mobile screen.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

You can learn more about viewport meta tag in [css-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/html/responsive-meta-tag/)